# .NET Core 2.2 Migration Builder unable to remove index

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to remove an index/foreign key from a column in my IdentityUserRole table called UserRole.

UserRole has 2 columns. UserId and RoleId. Both are primary keys.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    
    var rolesTable = modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().ToTable("Role");
    var userRolesTable = modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");
    var userClaimsTable = modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ToTable("UserClaim");
    var usersTable = modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Role>(builder =>
    {
        builder.Metadata.RemoveIndex(new[] { builder.Property(u => u.NormalizedName).Metadata });
    });
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>(builder =>
    {
        builder.Metadata.RemoveIndex(new[] { builder.Property(u => u.RoleId).Metadata});
    });
    

}
```

However, whenever i run my migration and update the database, this index still appears:

> IX_UserRole_RoleId for column RoleId

EDIT: This is the generated migration

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "UserRole",
    columns: table => new
    {
        UserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
        RoleId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_UserRole", x => new { x.UserId, x.RoleId });
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_UserRole_Role_RoleId",
            column: x => x.RoleId,
            principalTable: "Role",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_UserRole_User_UserId",
            column: x => x.UserId,
            principalTable: "User",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });

migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_UserRole_RoleId",
    table: "UserRole",
    column: "RoleId");
```

Comment: Does the migration give you any errors (Could there be a foreign key link with data that’s preventing it from running correctly?).  My suggestion would be to back up the DB and then generate the SQL for the migration, then run that manually.  You usually get more info from the DBMS

Comment: No errors when run from my package manager console.

Comment: This is a new database that I am performing a migration for as well.

Comment: Can you post the migration that is generated from this change?

Comment: Hi @PaulMichaels, I've edited my question with it.

Comment: You may need to manually edit the migration: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/6239

Comment: Oh man..that is something I don't want to touch on. Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: From the link, it looks like there may be an issue with removing indexes.  Is there a reason that you want to avoid changing the migration?  You don’t have to add the actual SQL, just add a call to DropIndex

Comment: I was thinking that I wouldnt want to manually adjust the migrations just in case.

Comment: You're generally fine to do so, providing that you don't alter a previous migration (i.e. one that's actually run - at least against a database that you can't revert).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By convention EF Core adds index for each FK column which is not the leading part of another index. Even though you don't have queries which use these indexes, in general they are useful for enforcing the FK constraint as well for implementing cascade delete, so de facto they are standard in relational database design (similar to unique indexes used to enforce unique/PK constraints etc.) But that's not the question here.

You may consider it as defect, but indexes introduced by convention cannot be removed even though you use the explicit `RemoveIndex` metadata API. It removes them, but then they are automatically added back.

This is because the EF Core conventions are no applied statically. They are implemented by classes which listen to different model metadata changes which trigger "reapplying" the convention.

Shortly, you can't remove such indexes with metadata / fluent API. If you really want to remove them (which I don't recommend), you should manually edit the generated migrations and remove corresponding create / drop commands from both `Up` and `Down` methods.